# Automatically saving changes in a cell to object when editing finishes?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uitableview

im having a real nightmare with my project where i need to save cell contents to an object, for each object in an array. I cant get this to work by looping through table cells adn array objects and trying to match them all up.

So my next idea was to add didFinishEditing related functions into the cellForRowAt function?

Im not sure this would work either, but this is what i have:

[image]

Each row here has a label for the set, a picker for the reps that can be scrolled to a number, and a textfield to put a weight. Then i save each row as an object storing the set, rep and weight.

Issue is when editing this, how can i save these again overwriting the old values? Hence my plan above to use didFinishEditing methods.

My previous plan was the code below, but i cant figure out the annotated part. So i was hoping someone had guidance on how i can approach saying when editing rather than this save button function that doesnt work!

```
    func saveUserExerciseSets() {

    if userExercise == nil {
        print("CREATING A FRESH SET OF SETS FOR THE NEW EXERCISE")
        for cell in self.customSetsTable.visibleCells as! Array<NewExerciseTableViewCell> {
            print("SAVING THESE CELLS \(customSetsTable.visibleCells)")
            let newUserExerciseSet = UserExerciseSet(context: self.managedObjectContext)

            newUserExerciseSet.setPosition = Int64(cell.setNumber.text!)!
            newUserExerciseSet.setReps = Int64(cell.repsPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0))
            newUserExerciseSet.parentExerciseName = self.userExerciseName.text

            if self.localeIdentifier == "en_GB" {
                let kgWeight = Measurement(value: Double(cell.userExerciseWeight.text!)!, unit: UnitMass.kilograms)
                newUserExerciseSet.setWeight = kgWeight as NSObject?
                newUserExerciseSet.initialMetricSystem = self.localeIdentifier

            } else if self.localeIdentifier == "en_US" {
                let lbsWeight = Measurement(value: Double(cell.userExerciseWeight.text!)!, unit: UnitMass.pounds)
                newUserExerciseSet.setWeight = lbsWeight as NSObject?
                newUserExerciseSet.initialMetricSystem = self.localeIdentifier
            }

            let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<UserExercise> = UserExercise.fetchRequest()
            fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", self.exerciseNameToAddTo!)

            do {
                let parentExercise = try self.managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest).first
                parentExercise?.addToExercisesets(newUserExerciseSet)
                print("SET ADDED TO EXERCISE")
            } catch {
                print("Fetching Routine Failed")
            }
        }

    } else if self.userExercise != nil {
        print("UPDATING EXISTING SETS FOR THE EXISTING EXERCISE")

        let cells = self.customSetsTable.visibleCells as! Array<NewExerciseTableViewCell>

        for cell in cells {
            let exerciseSets = self.userExercise?.exercisesets?.allObjects as! [UserExerciseSet]
            let sortedexerciseSets = exerciseSets.sorted { ($0.setPosition < $1.setPosition) }
            let cellsSet = sortedexerciseSets //match the sortedexerciseSets set object to the cell index positions

            cellsSet.setPosition = Int64(setsCell.setNumber.text!)!
            cellsSet.setReps = Int64(setsCell.repsPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0))

            if self.localeIdentifier == "en_GB" {
                let kgWeight = Measurement(value: Double(cell.userExerciseWeight.text!)!, unit: UnitMass.kilograms)
                cellsSet.setWeight = kgWeight as NSObject?
            } else if self.localeIdentifier == "en_US" {
                let lbsWeight = Measurement(value: Double(cell.userExerciseWeight.text!)!, unit: UnitMass.pounds)
                cellsSet.setWeight = lbsWeight as NSObject?
            }
            cellsSet.parentExerciseName = self.userExerciseName.text
        }
    }

    do {
        try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        print("THE SET HAS BEEN SAVED")
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
    }
    delegate?.didFinishEditing()
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? NewExerciseTableViewCell
        else {
            fatalError("Unexpected Index Path")
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.customBackgroundGraphite()
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    cell.repsPicker.dataSource = self
    cell.repsPicker.delegate = self
    configure(cell, at: indexPath)
    return cell
}

func configure(_ cell: NewExerciseTableViewCell, at indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // configuring cells when theres a loaded exercise causes the issues --------------------
    if self.userExercise != nil {
        print("RESTORING CELLS FOR THE EXISTING EXERCISE")
        let unsortedExerciseSets = self.userExercise?.exercisesets?.allObjects as! [UserExerciseSet]
        let exerciseSets = unsortedExerciseSets.sorted { ($0.setPosition < $1.setPosition) }

        let cellsSet = exerciseSets[indexPath.row]

        cell.setNumber.text = String((indexPath.row) + 1)

        let indexRow = Int(cellsSet.setReps)
        print("INDEX ROW INT IS \(indexRow)")

        cell.repsPicker.selectRow(indexRow, inComponent: 0, animated: true) //fix this crashing issue!

        let localeIdentifier = Locale(identifier: UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "locale") as! String)
        let setWeight = cellsSet.setWeight as! Measurement<UnitMass>
        let formatter = MassFormatter()
        formatter.numberFormatter.locale = localeIdentifier
        formatter.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

        if localeIdentifier.usesMetricSystem {
            let kgWeight = setWeight.converted(to: .kilograms)
            let finalKgWeight = formatter.string(fromValue: kgWeight.value, unit: .kilogram)
            let NumericKgResult = finalKgWeight.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.").inverted)
            cell.userExerciseWeight.text = NumericKgResult
        } else {
            let lbsWeight = setWeight.converted(to: .pounds)
            let finalLbWeight = formatter.string(fromValue: lbsWeight.value, unit: .pound)
            let NumericLbResult = finalLbWeight.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.").inverted)
            cell.userExerciseWeight.text = NumericLbResult
        }

    } else if self.userExercise == nil {
        print("NEW SET CELL ADDED FOR FRESH EXERCISE")
        cell.setNumber.text = String((indexPath.row) + 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post cellForRow method? How do you populate the table view to make sure the cell data doesn't change when it's no longer visible?

Comment: I have added cellforRowAt to the OP, ots populated via an entity relationship passed over in segue when the VC is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this to match the setIds correctly. That's where I think the issue is.

```
for x in sortedexerciseSets {

     if x.setPosition == Int64(setsCell.setNumber.text!)! {

       //save 
      }           
}
```

Comment: this resolved it integrating it with the code in the OP to use my initially proposed method!

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to do it would be to have an array of those sets (I guess, since you tagged core-data, they are instances of NSManagedObject?). When user does ANY change in the cell (write new value in the text field or scroll to another value for reps) you need to update the approproate object in your array immediately. Then you could call save on NSManagedObjectContext when you're sure you want to save changes, or just call rollback on the context to cancel all changes.

Comment: thanks yes this is what i wrote in my OP as to what i thought i should do, the question was about how to achieve it, where do i implement this functionality? as i cant use any didFinishEditing commands inside of cellforrowat for example